# Can you store numbers, bools, etc in a postgres jsonb field?

Tags: json, postgresql, casting, type-conversion

I have one field in my data model that can be practically anything: a number, a string, a bool, or a complex object.

Can I store this in postgres as jsonb?

```
id | response (jsonb)
------------
1  | "hello"
2  | 3
3  | { "firstName": "bob", "lastName" : "wilson" }
4  | True
```

I'm currently getting this error when I try to save a numeric json value into that column:

```
column "response" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text
```

Is it only possible if I save it in an object structure, like this?

```
{ "value" : "hello" }
{ "value" : 3 }
{ "value" : ... }
```

I'd rather do it the first way if it's possible.

Comment: Depending on the size of what you want to save, you can encode as JSON, then save as VARCHAR, then retrive as JSON again...

Comment: You can save any [valid json value](http://json.org) to either `json` or to a `jsonb` column. But you *cannot* bind it as string/`text`/`varchar`, if you use prepared statements (use casts instead in sql, like `UPDATE ... SET json_col = $1::json` or bind it as `unknown`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (j jsonb);
insert into t (j) values
    (to_json(1)::jsonb),
    (to_json('hello'::text)::jsonb),
    (to_json(true)::jsonb)
;
select * from t;
    j    
---------
 1
 "hello"
 true
```

Notice that the string must be cast before being converted to json.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that even though numbers, bools, and strings have valid JSON representations, the JSON standard requires that the top-level value be either an array or object.

So I shouldn't be attempting to do it this way. Instead, I should store it as an object.